# How to print multiple iframe within hidden div.It is working in Chrome and firefox.But bot working in IE

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome

How to print multiple i frame in IE

its printing only one iframe.
iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);

Comment: We'll need to see more code in order to help you.

Comment: <div id="myfrm4" style="display:none">
    <iframe name="myframe" id="myframe" src="#.html" type="text/html"</iframe>
    <iframe name="myframe" id="myframe" src="#.html" type="text/html" </iframe>
    <iframe name="myframe" id="myframe" src="#.html" type="text/html" </iframe>
    <iframe name="myframe" id="myframe" src="#.html" type="text/html" </iframe>
 </div>